# Pass a value via URL to a node edit form and use it to redirect after saving the node

Tags: forms, redirection, 9

I have a node that includes a series of embedded views. When displaying, I have to pass a value via URL arguments (http://example.org/node/x?id=y), so that the views can get the appropriate information. The user needs to be able to edit this node, but when they save and return to the node it has lost the *id=y* part and the display is incomplete.

I know I can use `hook_form_alter()` to redirect, but I can't figure out how can I redirect after the node is saved using that URL argument?

Comment: @apaderno - Thank you for editing my post to make clear.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I am using Drupal 9

Answer (score 0):

Using `hook_form_alter()`, you can add a submission handler that sets the redirection. The code for the submission handler would be similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_node_edit_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $id = \Drupal::request()->query->get('id');
  $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $node->id()], [query => ['id' => $id]]);
}
```

The code for `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` would simply be the following one.

```php
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  // Since this hook is invoked for every node, check its content type.
  if ($node->getType() == 'the content type you are interested in') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_edit_submit';
  }
}
```

The `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` implementation should be named `mymodule_form_node_<content_type_machine_name>_alter()`. (Replace *mymodule* with the module machine name, `<content_type_machine_name>` with the content type machine name.) In this case, since the hook is invoked only for a content type, it doesn't need to check the node content type before adding the submission handler.

Comment: Something is not working.  If my url is ```http://example.org/node/123?id=57```, after submitting the form it is redirected to ```http://example.org/node/123?id```. So it seems that the id query parameter is not getting added. If I do a ```dpm($id)``` in either of the functions, it shows as NULL - which makes me think that the query is not getting captured from the original node. Have I missed something?